# CSS display:table-cell with div inside table

Tags: css, html

How to make display:table-cell style works (or look-alike alternative) if divs with style table-row are inside table cells? (see the link)

http://jsfiddle.net/ELKQg/460/

I'd like the container1 div behave like the container2.

code: (if the link were to become unreachable)

html:

```
<div id="container1" class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">aaaa</div>
        <div class="cell expand">b</div>
        <div class="cell">c</div>
    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">d</div>
        <div class="cell expand">eeeee</div>
        <div class="cell">f</div>
    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="container2" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">aaaa</div>
        <div class="cell expand">b</div>
        <div class="cell">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">d</div>
        <div class="cell expand">eeeee</div>
        <div class="cell">f</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.container{width: 500px;overflow:hidden; /* instead of clearfix div */}  
 div { border:1px solid;padding: 1px;}    
.row {display:table-row;}
.cell {display:table-cell;}
.expand{overflow:hidden;width:100%;}
```

Comment: sorry, my fault, i forgot table { width:100%; }
here's the correct one : http://jsfiddle.net/ELKQg/463/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The extra `<table>` containing your `<div>`s in `.container1` needs to have `width: 100%`
2. `display: table-cell` elements don't necessarily need a containing `display: table-row` as long as the parent is `display: table`. Set the `.row` to that (ideally you'd re-name it, seeing as the rule no longer makes sense)

Fixed and forked your demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/barney/ahMg8/

Comment: your fork dont work, even container2 lose the cells "table style" (every cell has the same width of the largest cell, despite its content)

Comment: Both tables look identical on Firefox and Chrome. Can't check IE because it's got some weird restrictions where I work. The code changes I made don't touch `.container2`.

Comment: you changed .row {
    display:table-row;
} to .row {
    display:table;
} this way it lose the cells "alignment"...like a grid. Here what i see with your code http://imgh.us/Cattura2.png and what is should be http://imgh.us/Cattura_1.png (third and forth row)

Comment: Right! I see what you're saying. In that case, what you're after is impossible in pure HTML + CSS, because you want rows in different tables to share the same column width. That's what tables are intrinsically for: making their immediate rows share columns. Sometimes people will make disparate tables (and non-tables) match each-others dimensions by using Javascript. Would that be a valid solution for you?

Comment: I was afraid of. As last resource i'll use javascript. Thanks you, at least now i know it can't be done without javascript. Now i'll try to replace GWT VerticalPanel with some div based container.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table` for the parent table before using `display:table-cell`

Comment: i've added the edited one in the main post comment, it don't seem to work, have i get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `td`'s instead of divs inside `tr`:

```
<div id="container1" class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">aaaa</td>
            <td class="cell expand">b</td>
            <td class="cell">c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">d</div>
            <td class="cell expand">eeeee</td>
            <td class="cell">f</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELKQg/462/)

Comment: sorry, i can't: the table is from a GWT Verical Panel and div from Focus Panel and i can't change them.