# How about this way for vertically positioning text inside a div?

Tags: css

I have always looked for alternative ways for middle positioning text inside a div, There are many ways out there, from javascript dynamic positioning to the latest css units vw and vh.
The other day I realised that there is another way that was always right in-front of me all time along, but I never used it, namely by displaying a div as a table cell 
`display:table-cell;vertical-position:middle` http://jsfiddle.net/manolis/TPKsf/
I haven't used it yet in production but I'm wondering what are the pros and cons of using this solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:table-cell` may have some ramifications that you don't want.  From a quick search around, I found some relevant info:

- `display:table-cell` elements *should* be inside a `display:table` element (but [don't necessarily need to be in a `display:table-row` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15134827/143295)).
- `display:table-cell` elements will not have a margin.
- tables do not automatically take up the full width like `div`s do.
- [QuirksMode docs on `display:table`](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html#table) has some interesting information and even a "playground" where you can easily change the `display` of elements to see how they interact.

**My take:** If you properly form it inside a `display:table` element, and you only need it for limited purposes where table formatting is fine, then go for it (e.g., vertically centering a 404 error as the only box on a page).

Comment: You are right! table-cell might introduce some side effects, but I think it still might be worth it in some cases, until vh and vw are widely suported

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer 7 and earlier versions don't support “display:table-cell”, IE8 supports, but requires a !DOCTYPE, you can find more explanation here - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-reference/css-display-property.php

Alternatively you can also vertical align text in a div through setting value of the line-height property equal the height of div, like:

Your CSS:

```
div{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div><a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">About</a> | <a href="#">Contact</a></div>
```

The above style rule align the text inside a div vertically center or middle. You can check out this page to know how line-height works - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-text.php

Comment: I don't think he's asking for other ways, since he says that he knows there are a lot of other ways. I think he wants to know the pros/cons of the one way that he spelled out.

Comment: Yep I agree with @bzupnick no need for other ways, especially in the case of middle align which is a topic everyone stumbles upon... But since you posted an example, your example only applies to one liners, if you have more than one lines it will cause havoc :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that, it doesn't uses `vertical-align`... But could be useful for you...

**Css:-**

```
#box{
    position:absolute; top:50%; left:0;
    margin-top:-50px; /*Half of height...*/
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    border:5px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPKsf/4/)

Comment: This method requires you to know the height in pixels in which you'll centre the content.